# "assignment of read-only variable"

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa

I have the following code:

```
bool MyClass::MoveFileToTrash()
{
    bool ret;
    NSArray *files = [NSArray arrayWithObject:url];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] recycleURLs:files completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *newURLs, NSError *error)
    {
        ret = error != nil;
    }];
    return ret;
}
```

The variable "ret" is not declared as "const", but nevertheless I'm getting the subj error.

Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: That's not C++, perhaps Objective-C++?

Comment: This is pure Objective-C, actually.

Comment: @Sulthan, no, it is not. I believe the function signature make it pretty clear - this is NOT purely Objective-C++.

Comment: @Igor The function is a C function. Objective-C is an extension of C. That means this is still pure Objective-C. Even in Objective-C there are C functions. There is nothing C++ in there. That `bool` type comes from C99 which is the most common C dialect used with Obj-C.

Comment: @Sulthan, that's unfortunately being taiken away by the edit - I explicitely put "C++" tag with the post. And it was there for a reason. But now I changed the post and added the "c++" tag. Hopefully now it is more clear. Thank you.

Comment: @Igor Oh, I see that now but maybe you should roll that change back. The signature (and C++)  has nothing to do with the problem. It's an Obj-C problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem, the one the compiler is reporting, is that by default the *value* of local variables is what is captured by a block - which means the local variable cannot be modified by the block only its value used.

If you add the `__block` modifier to a local variable then a block will capture the *variable* - which means the block sees the value of the variable as it is at the time the block is executed and can modify the variable.

Adding the modifier will fixed your immediate compiler error...

**However** your code will not work. The block is being passed as a completion handler to `recycleURLs:completionHandler:` and it will be invoked asynchronously after the recycle operation has completed. This will probably be *after* the method call itself has returned and the following `return` statement executed; so the value returned will not be the value set by the block, as the block will not have actually been executed yet.

It is recommended you change your code to an asynchronous design; e.g. maybe by passing a completion handler to your `MoveFileToTrash`, which you then pass to `recycleURLs:completionHandler:`.

A, generally to be avoided, alternative option is to use some form of blocking, e.g. semaphores, to effectively invoke `recycleURLs:completionHandler:` synchronously. While possible this is not recommended, there is a reason the call is asynchronous - it can take some time to complete - and treating it synchronously might effectively freeze your app for a period.

HTH

Comment: I am not very familiar with Objective-C++. Could you give an example of such passing?

Comment: @Igor - I assume the example you are asking for is when you rewrite your function to take a block as its completion handler, i.e. follow the same pattern as `recycleURLs:completionHandler:`. Well that is a starting example for you - look at the type of `recycleURLs:completionHandler:`. But really you need to go and read up on blocks and asynchronous patterns, its a topic larger than this answer. Hopefully the issues mentioned above will guide you in your research, and when you have learnt and produced some code if you get stuck post another question and I'm sure someone will help.

Comment: yes, you guessed correctly. The problem is however that this code I'm trying to write is a mix of C++ and Objective-C++. So how do I pass the Cocoa function pointer to the pure C++ function. Right now the signature is as follows: bool MyClass::MoveFileToTrash()". I do understand what you mean by saying synchronous vs asynchronous execution and that my code wouldn't work. But because the code is a mix of C++ and Cocoa I have no idea how to work it out. Thank you.

Comment: Read up on *blocks*, what you are calling a "Cocoa function pointer". They are an extension to C(++) not just an Obj-C feature. You can use them in C(++) code just as you do in Obj-C code. Note there is nothing preventing you from declaring your C(++) function to take a C(++) style function pointer as its continuation handler and for you to call that passed function within the block you pass to the Obj-C method. HTH

Answer (score -1):

I believe `ret` needs to be have a `__block` modifier for it to be assignable inside of a block.